# Eiffel: like Precursor

Tags: covariance, eiffel

Maybe I'm going to far, but Eiffel is such a beauty that I'd like to be able to say `like precursor` for Result class of function

My point is

```
deferred class A
    give_me_foo: STRING
    deferred
    end
end -- class

class real_foo
    give_me_foo: like Precursor
        do
        end
end -- class
```

Would be nice, does it exist?

**Update**: I let a wish on Eiffel site [here](https://www.eiffel.org/resources/wish/1032/detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, however this is possible:

```
give_me_foo: like {A}.give_me_foo
```

which is less elegant but more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

What would `like Precursor` mean? When I read your question, I assumed that the example would mean like A, i.e. the function's Result would have to conform to the precursor class `A`. But the other person who has answered your question has interpreted it differently. I think the other person's interpretation is probably what you intended, but I don't think the proposed `like Precursor` syntax would be a good idea because it's certainly ambiguous.

Comment: Whats the TYPE of Precursor? it returns a TYPE no? as like Current, Current is the TYPE of current Object or am I wrong? As `like give_me_foo` but without a named function, is it ambigous or did you not understand my idea/concept?

Comment: Okay, so you mean the type of the Precursor function. It wasn't obvious to me that this was what you meant, because the syntax resembles `like Current`, which has a very different meaning. I think it's bound to confuse new Eiffel users. As the other answer showed, we already have an explicit and concise means of anchoring the function's result type, with no ambiguity about how to read it.

Comment: you mean `like {A}.give_me_foo`, thats ok, but I have to change on 2 places if I want to change my A class inheritence ;-), but I understand your avoid confusion goal. Thx!